# How to relate two polar coordinate systems with different origins

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Suppose I have a polar coordinate system defined by $\theta$ and $R$. How do I relate this system to a new polar coordinate system $(\nu, r)$ whose origin lies at $\theta=\theta_0$, $R=d$?

My first instinct is to do a Jacobian, but I think it only relates areas, since it's defined only by derivatives.

Cheers